# Alternative of if-else and switch statements

Tags: java, javascript, conditional-statements

I have the following code in Java:

```
public void doSomething(int i) {
    if (i == 12) {
        // order should be same
        up();
        left();
        stop();
    }
    if (i == 304) {
        // order should be same
        right();
        up();
        stop();
    }
    if (i == 962) {
        // order should be same
        down();
        left();
        up();
        stop();
    }
}
// similar code can be done using switch case statements.
// all the function can have any functionality and might not resemble to the name given to them.
```

Now if I am asked not to use either of if-else and switch case statements, then what can be done? The code can be done in either Java or JavaScript.

Comment: Just making sure, you actually *can* use JS ([this language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals))? If so, that's easy.

Comment: Create an object with methods named like `'12'` and call your functions in that method.

Comment: Use a dictionary for each key you will have have list of functions as value and based on the key you pick the functions in list and iterate the list and call each function.

Comment: i don't think its possible, if there is a logic behind the number its might be possible. but if its just a number then you must use some conditional statements to identify the number.

Comment: @Puru--:thought of doing that as well but even then, I needed if-else statement to start with..

Comment: I will never understand the pedagogical reasons for asking students to "do X, but without using Y, the clearly correct method, or Z another valid, if awkward solution"

Comment: "in either Java or JavaScript" makes no sense. They are two very different languages with two very different domains. To answer your question, both languages supply several multiway ifs: `if-then-elseif-else` and some sort of `switch`. Your current implementation is defective because it hits _each_ `if` test rather than bailing out after the first match. That's probably what the instructor is getting at.

Comment: A code-review kind of comment: if that was actual code, you will want to hide those magic numbers behind constants (or whatever device your language of choice provides you).

Comment: i think you should be aware just to remind you JAVA != JAVASCRIPT

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you can use JavaScript, you can use a object with functions:

```
function doSomething(i) {
  var obj = {};

  obj[12] = function () {
    // order should be same
    up();
    left();
    stop();
  };
  obj[304] = function () {
    // order should be same
    right();
    up();
    stop();
  };
  obj[962] = function () {
    // order should be same
    down();
    left();
    up();
    stop();
  };

  // apparently we can't use any conditional statements
  try {
    obj[i]();
  } catch (e) {}
}
```

If only `if` and `switch` statements aren't allowed, replace all the `if` statements with the logical AND operator (`&&`):

```
function doSomething(i) {
  (i == 12) && (
    // order should be same
    up(),
    left(),
    stop()
  );

  (i == 304) && (
    // order should be same
    right(),
    up(),
    stop()
  );

  (i == 962) && (
    // order should be same
    down(),
    left(),
    up(),
    stop()
  );
}
```

Comment: second is using the if statement, but the first deserves an up Vote ;-)

Comment: If OP prohibits using even conditional statements it won't be acceptable :)

Comment: Just want to point out that the second suggestion only works in languages that use short-circuit evaluation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation  from the top of my head only pascal does not use it.

Comment: @Hoffmann, but OP is talking about Java and JS, both of which short-circuit.

Comment: Instead of the try/catch, I personally think this is more readable: `obj[i] && obj[i]();`

Answer (score 17):

Here is a simple way to accomplish this in JavaScript:

```javascript
function up()    { console.log("up");    }
function down()  { console.log("down");  }
function left()  { console.log("left");  }
function right() { console.log("right"); }
function stop()  { console.log("stop");  }

var fnmaps = {
    12:  [up, left, stop],
    304: [right, up, stop],
    962: [down, left, up, stop]
};

function doSomething(i) {
    var fnmap = fnmaps[i] || [], j;
    for (j = 0; j < fnmap.length; j++) {
        fnmap[j]();
    }
}

doSomething(12);
doSomething(304);
doSomething(962);
```

Functions can be added/ordered simply by editing the map variable.

Answer (score 12):

You can make a dictionary of input-to-action. In Java this would be a `Map<Integer, Runnable>`, with, for instance*:

```
map.put(12, () -> {
    up();
    left();
    stop();
});
```

Then, you can get the appropriate `Runnable` and run it:

```
Runnable action = map.get(i);
if (action != null) {
    action.run();
} else {
    // some default action
    // This is the "default" case in a switch, or the "else" in an if-else
}
```

The if-else there isn't strictly necessary, but without it, you'll get a `NullPointerException` if `i` isn't an expected value — that is, one of the values you put into the map.

The idea is similar in JavaScript, though with objects instead of `Map`s, functions (probably anonymous) instead of `Runnable`s, etc.

---

<sub>This code is for Java 8. In Java 7 and below, you'd do:</sub>

```
map.put(12, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        up();
        left();
        stop();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Puru-- The idea works in Java 7 just as well. But yes, you'll need to create an anonymous class instead of using a lambda.

Comment: @sura True, although it's not required if you're confident that `i` is always an expected value. (And if you're wrong about that, you'll get a `NullPointerException` at `action.run()`.)

Comment: @yshavit, I suppose you could `try...catch` the NPE instead of creating a null-guard with `if...else`. :)

Comment: @BrianS You could, but it's a generally a bad idea. If the Runnable itself has a bug and throws a NPE, you'd never know because of that catch-and-ignore. Much better to let that propagate up so that something can yell at you about it.

Comment: Who says you have to ignore the exception? (Not that I think try/catch is a _good_ substitute for if/else, merely that in this instance it _can_, and meets the OP's requirements.)

Answer (score 4):

Then do it with while and break, there is no other way without condition check

```
public void doSomething(int i) {

while(i == 12) {
// order should be same
    up();
    left();
    stop();
break;
    }

while(i == 304) {
// order should be same
    right();
    up();
    stop();
break;
    }

while(i == 962) {
// order should be same
    down();
    left();
    up();
    stop();
break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternative, equally awful: (i == 12 && (up (), left (), stop ())); (i == 304 && (right (), up (), stop ())); (i == 962 && (down (), left (), up (), stop ()));

Answer (score 4):

Wahahahahaha, you saved my day :) This should work, no way to test right now..

```
public void doSomething(int i) {

try {
    int x = 1/(12-i); // fails for i==12
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        up();
        left();
        stop();
}
```

and so on, enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

for js u may try this:

```
// define ur actions here
var actions = {
  "12" : function () { up(); left(); stop(); },
  "304" : function () { right(); up(); stop(); },
  "962" : function () { down(); left(); up(); stop(); }
};

function doSomething(i) {
  var fn = actions[i];
  try {
    fn();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
//
doSomething(12); //invoke here
```

Comment: very smartly written.

Answer (score 1):

Look, **naturally** you should inspect a conditional statement with a conditional expression!
Now, if you don't want to do this, you can do it unnaturally like this:

first do this for all methods (up,down,...)

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method;
try {
  method = obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName, param1.class, param2.class, ..);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
  // ...
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
  // ...
}
```

instead of an integer that you pass to the `doSomething`, use an array containing name of the methods that you want to call and inside a for loop call each method this way:

Then you invoke that method by calling

```
try {
  method.invoke(obj, arg1, arg2,...);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
```

**Unfortunately Java has not delegates**!

Comment: While I believe this approach will _work_ (as in, it will produce the desired result), reflection is a needlessly complicated solution to this problem, IMO.

Comment: @BrianS- Indeed as I already said the most natural way to do this in java is using if statement, however as OP doesn't want it, I tried to do it as close as possible to c# delegates, that is missing in java.

Comment: The common Java solution is some variant on the Observer pattern (yshavit's answer is a simplified version). I will admit, though, that several years ago I [wrote a class](http://clockworkgear.blogspot.com/2010/06/java-callbacks-using-javalangreflect.html) to achieve your solution in a reusable fashion.

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be solved using OOP techniques.

In java it would look like this:

```
public abstract class AObject{
   public abstract  void doSomething();
   public void  up(){
      //do something here
   }
   public void down(){
      //do something here
   }
   public void left(){
      //do something here
   }
   public void right(){
      //do something here
   }       
   public void stop(){
      //do something here
   }     
}


public class AObject12 extends AObject{
   public void doSomething(){
      up();
      left();
      stop();
   }
}

public class AObject304 extends AObject{
   public void doSomething(){
      right();
      up();
      stop();
   }
}

public class AObject962 extends AObject{
   public void doSomething(){
      down();
      left();
      up();
      stop();
   }
}
```

Executing doSomething on a instance of a concrete class will trigger the appropriate behavior. So no more if/else is necesary. See code below for an example:

```
AObject A12 = new AObject12();
A12.doSomething();
// Will run Up left stop in that order

AObject A304 = new AObject304();
A304.doSomething();
// Will run right Up stop in that order

AObject A962 = new AObject962();
A962.doSomething();
// Will run down left up stop in that order
```

Some more info on this kind of programming can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29

If you would like to be able to change the behavior of the object dynamicly you could consider applying a state pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

Comment: how do you call one conditionally now ?

Comment: @Ven You call do instance on an instance of a object and it will execute the code belonging to that instance. Lets say you would like this behavior to be settable. then you could consider using a State Pattern : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern.

Comment: But how do you instantiate the correct class ? You're not answering the main question here.

Comment: That's still incorrect, you're executing every behavior, not one depending on "i"'s value.

Comment: The value of i is represented in the object its no longer a var. but it depends on the type of object. it still contains similar logic to the code the OP has but without the if/else just like the OP asked. :)

Comment: You're ignoring my previous comment. You're executing every single behavior in your last code.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, this should work..

```
public class IfTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IfTest ifTest = new IfTest();

        ifTest.doSomething(12);
        ifTest.doSomeThingWithoutIf(12);

        ifTest.doSomething(304);
        ifTest.doSomeThingWithoutIf(304);

        ifTest.doSomething(962);
        ifTest.doSomeThingWithoutIf(962);

        ifTest.doSomething(42);
        ifTest.doSomeThingWithoutIf(42);
    }

    public void doSomeThingWithoutIf(int i) {


        boolean x = i == 12 ? f12() : (i == 304 ? f304() : (i == 962 ? f962() : false));
    }

    public boolean f12() {

        up();
        left();
        stop();

        return true;
    }

    public boolean f304() {

        right();
        up();
        stop();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean f962() {

        down();
        left();
        up();
        stop();

        return true;
    }

    public void doSomething(int i) {

        if(i == 12) {
            // order should be same
            up();
            left();
            stop();
        }

        if(i == 304) {
            // order should be same
            right();
            up();
            stop();
        }

        if(i == 962) {
            // order should be same
            down();
            left();
            up();
            stop();
        }
    }

    private boolean retfalse() {
        return false;
    }

    private void down() {
        System.out.println("down");
    }

    private void right() {
        System.out.println("right");
    }

    private void stop() {
        System.out.println("stop");
    }

    private void left() {
        System.out.println("left");
    }

    private void up() {
        System.out.println("up");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would assume its because you did if-else with ternary operators. I think the OP wanted a solution without if-else or synonyms of it.

Comment: if that is the case, he must have stated "without using conditional operators" or so. I am not good in JS, but if I look at the solutions posted for Java, they either use Reflection or a Map/Dictionary etc. Both I find horrible vis a vis performance and memory footprint for such a simple thing

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree with you zencv. I was simply providing a possible reason as to why it was downvoted ;)

Answer (score 0):

The desired behavior can be achieved in JAVA by playing with the short-circuit of the logical AND operator as follows:

```
public static Boolean seq12() {
    // order should be same
    up();
    left();
    stop();
    return true;
}
public static Boolean seq304() {
    // order should be same
    right();
    up();
    stop();
    return true;
}
public static Boolean seq962() {
    // order should be same
    down();
    left();
    up();
    stop();
    return true;
}

public static void doSomething(int i) {
    Boolean tmp;
    tmp = (i == 12 && seq12());
    tmp = (i == 304 && seq304());
    tmp = (i == 962 && seq962());
}
```

This code is pretty straight-forward and relies on the fact that the logical AND operator only evaluates the second operand if the first one is *true*.